# how to understand this dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to quantitatively characterize this dynamical system / ODE:

$$ x'(t) = - y(t) $$
$$ y'(t) = \alpha \, \left[ \exp \left( x(t) - y(t) \right)  - 1 \right]$$
where $0 < \alpha < 1$ is usually close to 0 (say 0.001), and $y(0)$ is small (say $\pm 0.1$).

The system has a stable fixed point at the origin.  Qualitatively, the trajectories spiral in towards this fixed point.  Here are some trajectories starting from (-2, -0.1) with $
\alpha \in$ {1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4}: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o23NC.jpg.

Ideally, there would be some transformation of (x, y) into a kind of 'polar coordinates' that would give me a closed-form expression for the angle and for the radius (the latter of which would converge to zero).  (I'm putting 'polar coordinates' in scare quotes because it is clear that the actual radius $x^2 + y^2$ does not monotonically decrease.)

Barring that, I'd like to prove that some potential function converges to zero at a sufficiently quick (ideally exponential) rate.

##### A special case I do understand: linearizing around the origin

When $(x, y)$ are near the origin, the dynamics are well approximated by the linear dynamical system

$$ x'(t) = - y(t) $$
$$ y'(t) = \alpha \, \left[  x(t) - y(t) \right]$$

For this linear system, the potential function $\Phi(x, y) = \alpha x^2 - \alpha x y + y^2$ converges to zero at an exponential rate: it can be easily verified that $\frac{d \Phi}{dt} = \frac{d\Phi}{dx }\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{d \Phi}{dy} \frac{dy}{dt}= - \alpha \, \Phi$.
Thus, $\Phi(t) = \exp(- a t) \Phi(0)$.

However, I haven't succeeded at generalizing this analysis to the full case.

Answer (score 1):

since $\alpha$ is a small parameter, you have a singular system here.
this means the system has an initial layer/shock.

expand asymptotically externally, internally and perform matching procedure.

or you can use the method of averaging with a suitable Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Could you please clarify what you mean by matching procedure?   (Or point me towards a reference?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_matched_asymptotic_expansions?wprov=sfla1